# Sewer pump usage on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, electricity

There are sewer tanks where, when full, an electric sewer pump automatically turns on.

Is it a problem to pour water down the drain (washing hands, flushing the toilet) into such a sewer system?

One is not directly causing the pump to turn on -- it only kicks in if the tank becomes full.

Comment: Great question! I'm going to reword it to general terms so that it doesn't get closed as asking for a pask.

Comment: This would seem to involve gramma and be similar to using your refrigerator on Shabbos.

Comment: similar http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/773456/rabbi-aryeh-lebowitz/ten-minute-halacha-basement-plumbing-on-shabbos/

Answer (score 1):

Rav Aryeh Leibowitz [quotes](https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/773456/rabbi-aryeh-lebowitz/ten-minute-halacha-basement-plumbing-on-shabbos/) the Nishmas Shabbos ([6:75](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9696&st=&pgnum=120&hilite=) - *note this teshuva doesn't seem to be the correct address*) saying that if the electric sewer pump will only be activated after a few flushes, then it may only be considered a grama since it's a ko'ach sheni. Nonetheless, if you can pour the water out upstairs then it is better to do that, while it may be uncomfortable for a guest in the basement to go upstairs. He also notes that is would be better to wash your hands with the faucet rather than a utensil since using a utensil would be pouring the water directly into the container while just opening the pipe is less direct. He also notes that it's a *safek psik reisha* which might be considered a *davar she'eino miskaven,* so there is more room to be lenient. Rav Leibowitz concludes saying that many poskim are lenient with a commercial tank which holds more than one flush, though it's better to use an alternative bathroom if it's not uncomfortable.

Comment: That's what I heard when a shul renovated recently -- get a commercial system so that no one flush will definitively trigger it.

Comment: After doing some research it seems like it is in an addendum to Vol 6 #75. However unable to find the addendum online.

Answer (score 0):

Rabbi Meir Aaron who operates Halacha.CO who is a Chabad Rabbi, says it is permitted for the following reasons.

1 - It does not turn on specifically after each flush.

2 - Kovod HaBriyos is permitted when the prohibition is Rabinnic in nature.

See [here](http://halacha.co/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%91%D7%AA-%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%96-%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA/) for the entire answer and sources.